# center <a> tags below a form

Tags: html, css

[image]

how can i center the a tags below the form 
login.asp

```
<%
$Response->write(qq[

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="image_logo">
            <img class="img_logo" src="images/wearefamily-logo.png" alt="wearefamily-logo"/>
        </div>

        <h2 class="title_header">].gettext("title_header").qq[</h2>

        <div id="error_message_div">]. ( $Session->{login_error} ? gettext("wrong_credentials") :  "" ).qq[</div>

        <form class="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="index.asp" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input id="send" type="hidden" name="send" value="0" />
            <input id="uri" type="hidden" name="uri" value="">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="input" id="username" placeholder=].gettext("email").qq[ value="" /><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="input" id="password" placeholder=].gettext("password").qq[ value="" /><br>
            <input type="button" value=].gettext("signin").qq[ class="btn submit_btn"/><br>
        </form>
        <a class="form_link" href="index.asp?action=reset">].gettext("resetpassword").qq[</a><br>
        <a class="form_link" href="index.asp?action=register">].gettext("register").qq[</a>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>

]);

 %>
```

i would like to center the a tags below the form...the "reset your password" and "register to wearefamily kids" should be below sign button centered in the middle

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code given below

```
<div class="btn-block">
<a class="form_link" href="index.asp?action=reset">].gettext("resetpassword").qq[</a>
        <a class="form_link" href="index.asp?action=register">].gettext("register").qq[</a>
</div>



.btn-block {
  text-align:center;

}

.btn-block a {
display:inline-block;

}
```

Comment: excellent asnswer...thanks...i tried also without display:inline-block and also worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you didn't override the behavior of `a` elements because you haven't posted your css.

> `a` element is rendered as an inline element. This is default.

It means the `a` elements behaves like text so you can give `text-align:center;` to the parent of element for centering the `a` element.

```
.col-md-4
    {
       text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @AnshumanJasrotia I'm sorry to reply late. The explanation is added.